# JavaScript get Objects property

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Hello guys I've web page which have a lot of scripts, I need to get one by it's name. for e.g 'data'. I need to convert data from this script to one string.

Script is the following:

```
<script>data = [{'Id': '12344567', 'name': 'TestName','Amount': '1066.00', 'NumberTax': '34.00','tranasactionNumber':'139', 'otherInfo': [{'sku': 'ET|Adult','name': 'Test','category': 'Normal','price': '1032.0', 'quantity':'3'}]}];</script>
```

This data has array with some elements and another array inside.
Using my script I can only get info and create string with String elements from my data, but how can I get elements from inner array?

```
var json = '[{';
for (var i in data[0]) {
    console.log('type of data[0][i]  = ' + typeof data[0][i]);
    if (typeof data[0][i] === 'string') {
        json = json + '\'' + i + '\'' + ': ' + '\'' + data[0][i] + '\', ';
        console.log(i);
        console.log(data[0][i])
    } else {
        //Get infro from inner array
    }
}
json = json + '}]';
console.log(json);
```

Comment: please add the wanted result as well, maybe you have a look to [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), too.

Comment: JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `JSON.stringify(data)` to convert object to string instead of your function.

Answer (score 0):

To access the object inside the array you can use the following code:

```
var obj = data[0]['otherInfo'][0];
```

You can then use the same code you have above to loop over it and append its elements. If I understand correctly that if what you wish to do.